# MUI MonthPicker causes LocalizationProvider error in storybook

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datepicker, storybook

I am using MUI MonthPicker (MUI v5.x), it works okay in the code, but when I use the component in the storybook, it gives me the following error:

> MUI: Can not find utils in context. It looks like you forgot to wrap your component in LocalizationProvider, or pass dateAdapter prop directly.

My simplified code for the component is

```
export const MyMonthPicker = ({ value, onChange }) => (
    <Paper>
      <MonthPicker
        onChange={(newDate) => {
          onChange(newDate);
        }}
        date={value}
        disableFuture
      />
    </Paper>
  );
```

My story code is

```
...
import { AdapterDateFns } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDateFns";
import { LocalizationProvider } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider";

const meta: Meta<typeof MonthYearPicker> = {
  title: "MyProject/components/MyMonthPicker",
  component: MyMonthPicker,
  args: { value: new Date(), onChange: (value) => {} },
  decorators: [
    (Story) => (
      <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns} localeText={{}}>
        <Box sx={{ position: "relative" }}>
          <Story />
        </Box>
      </LocalizationProvider>
    ),
  ],
};

export default meta;
type Story = StoryObj<typeof MonthYearPicker>;

export const Default: Story = {};
```

I tried using other dateAdaptors with the same result (AdapterDayjs, AdapterLuxon, AdapterMoment).

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I raised it with MUI, but they could not reproduce it with the latest versons, so it may be just versions of MUI/Storybook I use.

Just in case someone has the same issue - I just used `StaticDatePicker` with `views` prop values `["month"]` and `["years"]` to replace `MonthPicker` and `YearPicker` respectively. They look almost the same, just had to made Month view header invisible with `display: none`. Did not have any problems with that component.